# How to optimize my code when left join two table according to the condition in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a field in table t called `type` which is to show the role ,When type equal student,it return student's name.When type equal teacher,it return teacher's name.Now I have left join two table,Can I left join one table?How to optimize my code?

```
select t.*,(CASE t.type WHEN 'student' THEN tStudent.sname 
ELSE tTeacher.tname END) as name 
from t
left join t_student tStudent on t.typeid=tStudent .id
left join t_teacher tTeacher on t.typeid=tTeacher.id
```

Comment: The major optimization is performed using indexes. Nevertheless, I miss some major info. What storage engine do you use? Do you have any indexes? Could you post sizes of the tables? Do you really want all the data?

Comment: innodb,id is the primary key of all three table

Comment: Honestly, I do not believe that there is a way significantly speed up your query if you select all the rows. Covering indexes may help, however, not significantly.

Answer (score 1):

This Should work

```
select 
   t.*, 
   (case 
   when t.type = 'student' then (select sname from tStudent where id = t.typeid)
      else (select tname from tTeacher where id = t.typeid)
      end) AS Name
from
     t
```

Comment: Can we have an EXPLAIN output for this query ? I wonder how this works. How efficient will this perform when compared to two left joins ?

Comment: I dont think it will be any different in performance but is just an alternative as the question asked for a solution with maybe 1 or less joins so this should work and maintain the effectiveness but i personally would use the joins as is alot cleaner and more than likely has an increased performance

Answer (score 1):

This is not an optimization, but an improvement on the code:

```
select t.*, coalesce(ts.sname, tt.tname) as name
from t left join
     t_student ts
     on t.typeid = ts.id and t.type = 'student' left join
     t_teacher tt
     on t.typeid = tt.id and t.type = 'teacher'  -- just a guess
```

The improved logic is to put the type conditions in the `on` clause.  The logic is cleaner, but I don't think this will have much affect on performance.

For performance, you want indexes on `t_student(id, name)` and `t_teacher(id, name)`.  These are covering indexes for the two tables in the query so the data pages never need to be referenced.

Comment: For performance, you want indexes on t_student(id, name) and t_teacher(id, name)-----I think the indexes should be  t_student(id) and t_teacher(id).Why should use name as index?

Comment: @flower . . . Those indexes are sufficient -- particularly if they are primary keys.  Adding `nam` is a small optimization so the original data pages do not need to be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.*,
    (CASE WHEN t.type = 'student' THEN tStudent.sname
        ELSE tTeacher.tname
    END) AS name
FROM t 
    LEFT JOIN t_student tStudent ON t.typeid = tStudent.id
    LEFT JOIN t_teacher tTeacher ON t.typeid = tTeacher.id;
```

There is no other way to use for expected output. LEFT JOIN is faster than subquery. please refer in attached link,

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/rewriting-subqueries.html

Comment: LEFT JOIN is faster than subquery.?? 
This is the first time I've heard that.